# Making User Control visible on a button in Windows Forms(C#)

Tags: c#, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

people. I'm trying to make a User Control visible on my Windows Form, on the press of a button in my Form. The User Control has been added to my main Form, and I've set its visibility to "false"".

The corresponding code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace When_Im_tired_of_researching_on_Stack_Overflow
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //Declaring an object of the user control "Diag_List1"
        Diag_List1 Pass = new Diag_List1(); 

        public Form1()
        {
          InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

     //The button's event handler that will make my User Control visible

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Pass.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I build and then press the button on the form, the User Control remains invisible. What's the issue?

Please forgive me if it's a dumb mistake that could be spotted in a second...I'm new to C# and Windows Forms (incidentally, to StackOverflow as well).

Comment: A control to be used by a form should be added the Form.Controls collection otherwise it is not considered for drawing on the form surface

Comment: I did,actually. Dragged it off the toolbox and then added it to the form. Isn't that the procedure?

Comment: When you drag the control off the toolbox it is added to the controls collection of the form. Now you need to make visible that instance of your control not create another instance and making it visible. What is the name assigned to your usercontrol on the designer surface of your form? This is the one to make visible

Comment: Right,Steve. The name of the particular instance used in the main Form was "Diag_List1". I didn't realize that the name of the user control(as used in the main form) referred to the instance of the User Control in that Form. But now it's crystal clear. I changed the UC object's name to "Pass", and removed the "Pass" object declaration statement from the above program. Worked like a charm, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

On Button Click Just you need to add this ::

```
if (! this.Controls.Contains(pass))
            this.Controls.Add(pass);

        pass.Visible = true;
```

Comment: I have already added the UserControl to the Form in the designer window itself. I dragged it off the toolbox and then placed it inside my Form. That's what this code is doing,right?

Comment: This adds the Diag_List1 control that you created through **code**, visible on your form (after adding it to the controls collection).  The original Diag_List1 control that you dragged onto the form is still there and invisible.  After pressing the button, you actually have two instances of Diag_List1 on your form (one visible and the other not).